# How can I plot the frequency components found using the FFT back to the time domain?

Tags: python, time-series, signal-processing, fft

** Edited with code below **

I used the scipy FFT package to plot the frequencies within my time series in a power spectrum:

[image: Sample FFT power spectrum]

My code used to plot the spectrum:

```
def run_fft(ts,column):
array_ = np.array(ts)
N = len(ts) # lenth of times series (days) - 8335 for our df
# Nyquist Sampling Criteria
T = 1/N # inverse of the sampling rate
x = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0/(2.0*T), int(N/2))
yr = fft(array_)
y = 2/N * np.abs(yr[0:np.int(N/2)]) # positive freqs only
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.figsize=(40,10)
plt.xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
plt.ylabel('Vibration (g)')
plt.title('Raw_signal for ' + str(column))
plt.show()
return y
```

How can I plot the seperate frequencies back in the time domain?
(ie. A time series plot with days on the x-axis and a sine wave for each of the biggest peaks seen in the power spectrum - such as the peak at 1200 above.)

Comment: you should show your code to gen above as stepping stone to do the inverse fft so folks can help you .. ideally copy N paste able

Comment: The power spectrum isn't enough to regenerate a time-domain signal.  You need the phase of all the frequency components as well.

Comment: @ScottStensland added it :)

Comment: @MattTimmermans what do you mean by "phase" of the freq components?